# Convert ajax to json

Tags: json, ajax

This is normal form submission to codeigniter framework. This is a ajax form submission. How to convert this to jason and send to below URL?

```
data: 'question=' + question + '&idquestion_table=' + idquestion_table + '&answer_1=' + answer_1 + '&answer_2=' + answer_2 + '&answer_3=' + answer_3 + '&answer_4=' + answer_4 + '&correct_answer=' + correct_answer + '&category=' + category,
                                url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin_question_controller'); ?>",
                                type: 'put',
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from?  Could you please show the form as well? It looks like you're using jquery, are you? Additional information and context will help yield more constructive answers.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully my code can help you to deal with your issue

```
<html>
    <input type="button" value="button" id="ID1" />
</html>
<script>
     $("#ID1").click(function () {
            var user = {
                username:'***@gmail.com',
                password:'!aA1234'
            };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://***/index.php',          
            data: user,          
            datatype: "json",
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                alert(textStatus);
            },
            success: function (data) {
             alert(data)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, specifically how it applies to the OPs question.

Comment: Hi @axlj Thank very much for your remind , I was losing put the " datatype: "json" in my code , by the way this is using ajax to send json data to server site thanks again .